# How pip install --editable changes python path when I run scripts under folders inside project root?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have a proyect built with FastApi. The project has this structure (simplified):

```
myproject/
    src/
        app/
            db/
            endpoints/
            schemas/
            __init__.py
            config.py
            main.py
        migrations/
        tests/
        venv/
        requirements.txt
        requirements.dev.txt
        setup.py
    dockerfile
    README.md
```

I install the project using a virtual environment:

```
cd src
python -m venv ./venv
pip install -r requirements.txt -r requirements.dev.txt
```

When I run `python app/main.py` from the `src/`, it raises an exception:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

Investigating with git I found that in a old version I used to install dependencies with other instructions:

```
cd src
python -m venv ./venv
pip install -e . -r requirememts.dev.txt
```

I replicated the pip installation with `-e` and it worked again. Also I added the lines to `main.py`:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

and discovered that the results are diferent, here the results:

with `pip install -r <...>`

```
> python app/main.py
['D:\\Projects\\myproject\\src\\app',
 'D:\\Projects\\myproject\\src\\venv',
 'D:\\Projects\\myproject\\src\\venv\\lib\\site-packages', .....]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from app.config import settings
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

with `pip install -e <...>`

```
> python app/main.py
['D:\\Projects\\myproject\\src\\app',
 'D:\\Projects\\myproject\\src\\venv',
 'D:\\Projects\\myproject\\src\\venv\\lib\\site-packages',
 'd:\\projects\\myproject\\src', ....]
<... Fast api & uvicorn logs here>
```

Why this happens?